# Spring - displaying transaction logs

Tags: mysql, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

We recently had an issue with a @transactional cron job that took forever to complete.

While the cron was executing we had many locks on our tables.

A simple update by id could not be executed.

We now try to minimize our transaction length to a minimum.

Is there an easy way to log all the transactions that takes longer than x milliseconds?

This will help us retrieve the candidate methods to be optimized.

Comment: The idea that i have is to use AOP, but i don't think is a good approach  :(